# Digitally Signed MSI still prompts UAC

Tags: windows-installer, uac

I have digitally signed a MSI Installer file however it still keeps prompting for a UAC. Is there anything I need to do to prevent the UAC notification from showing up?

Thanks

Comment: No, that would be useless if you could.

Answer (score 7):

Leppie is of course right. If you sign the MSI the UAC prompt does not go away (and there is no other way to do that either, short of turning off UAC). Instead the color of the prompt changes from "warning" yellow to "trustworthy" blue-green. Examples and further explanations can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Living-with-and-benefiting-from-User-Account-Control-from-Windows-Vista-Inside-Out).

Answer (score 0):

Digitally signing will only ensure that the publisher in UAC prompt will be named instead of an 'unknown publisher'. If you are running msi you can require administrator to install it. If it is written in WIX then have the attribute InstallPrivileges="elevated" for the Product element.
You can attach a proper manifest file elevating privileges to avoid a UAC prompt to setup.exe if you have setup.exe bootstrapper for your MSI.

Be aware that doing these things have other implications.

Answer (score 0):

Only applications signed by the Microsoft Windows publisher certificate can auto-elevate i.e. most Windows system components. 3rd party apps cannot.